# Can't get programmatically made UIButton to work - iPhone

Tags: iphone, button, uibutton

Here is the code I'm using:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *checkerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"black-yellow-checker" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *checkerImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:checkerPath];
    checkerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 230.0f, 320.0f, 280.0f)];
    [checkerView setImage:checkerImage];

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(45.0f, 175.0f, 230.0f, 50.0f);
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yellowButton" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBackHome:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:30];
    backButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [checkerView addSubview:backButton];
}

- (void)goBackHome:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"go back pressed");
}
```

Not sure why this doesn't work.  The button shows up, but when I press it nothing happens.  It doesn't even change to the "indented" image when I touch it.  Nothing.  Can't use IB, has to be programmatically.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UIImageView has `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO by default](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This prevents any subviews from getting touches.

You could either enable user interaction of the image view by

```
checkerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

or create a new UIView to include both `checkerView` and the `backButton`.

```
UIView* newView = ...
...
[newView addSubview:checkerView];
[newView addSubview:backButton];
```

Comment: AHA.  thought it would be yes by default.  since you're so darn knowledgable you should give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808087/where-to-find-what-mkdomainerror-error-4-means

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the forControlEvents: has to be UIControlEventTouchUpInside.